# Reference pointer conversion in javacpp

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, javacpp

I'm trying to map the following function in my header file to java using javacpp:

```
bool Foo( const void*& bar, uint32_t& baz );
```

This generates the following java code:

```
public native @Cast("bool") boolean Foo(, @Cast("uint32_t*") @ByRef IntPointer baz );
public native @Cast("bool") boolean Foo(, @Cast("uint32_t*") @ByRef IntBuffer baz );
public native @Cast("bool") boolean Foo(, @Cast("uint32_t*") @ByRef int[] baz );
```

Any guidance on what to put in my `infoMap` to get this to correctly map the reference pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to juggle with native memory pointer in java? A `uint64_t&` plus a couple of casts in C++ should do.

Comment: That was a bug. Fixed in this commit: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/commit/97d7ea6c08c6056a2ed715c38d3c67de50b24ce7